# IAM Policy for Parameter Store using Parameter tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-parameter-store, aws-iam-policy

I am quite new to whole AWS ecosystem so please bear with me. I am trying to come up with IAM policy by which I will allow certain groups to manage parameters in AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store.

I will have group for each "supplier" and they will have the opportunity to manage (get, update, remove) only parameters with corresponding tag.

```
Supplier1 -> parameter1 with tag Supplier:Supplier1 // with tag name Supplier and tag value Supplier1
Supplier1 -> parameter2 with tag Supplier:Supplier1
Supplier2 -> parameter3 with tag Supplier:Supplier2
Supplier2 -> parameter4 with tag Supplier:Supplier2
Supplier3 -> parameter5 with tag Supplier:Supplier3
```

So supplier1 would be able to get parameter1 & parameter2 and also would have the option to edit or even delete this parameter, same goes to other suppliers and their corresponding parameters.

I came up with this kind of policy definition. I assigned it to user Supplier1 and than I created parameter in Parameter Store (using my root account) that i tagged with tag name `Supplier` and value `Supplier1`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:DescribeParameters",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:DeleteParameter",
                "ssm:PutParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ssm:ResourceTag/Supplier": "Supplier1"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:DeleteParameter",
                "ssm:PutParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I log as Supplier1 I can see all tags that are created (due to DescribeParameters because I could not figure out if it is possible to filter by tags) but after clicking on required parameter I get: `User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/Supplier1 is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:eu-north-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:parameter/dev/ai/parameter1 with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy` error.

Could you please help me out?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As the answer has pointed out your deny policy statement takes priority over the allow statement. Also, to specify tags you can mention `aws:ResourceTag/Supplier` instead of `ssm:ResourceTag/Supplier`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your `Deny` policy overrides all `Allow` policies because in AWS IAM, an explicit deny always has precedence over an allow. Check the [documentation](https://go.aws/3ORmjrn) to learn more about the AWS IAM policy evaluation logic.

Try the following policy instead:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:DescribeParameters",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:DeleteParameter",
                "ssm:PutParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "ssm:ResourceTag/Supplier": "Supplier1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```